# why is my ggplot showing in black and white even though i have specified the colours for the lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot my ggplot but the colors are not following as it coded.

This is my data frame:

All_Flights_Combined_TimeOfDay

| Year | TimeOfDay | Delay_Count | Total_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2003 | Midnight | 9934 | 53321 |
| 2003 | Morning | 544278 | 2520172 |
| 2003 | Afternoon | 819926 | 2555560 |
| 2003 | Night | 485066 | 1359486 |
| 2004 | Midnight | 13458 | 71595 |
| 2004 | Morning | 687543 | 2782548 |
| 2004 | Afternoon | 1056605 | 2758242 |
| 2004 | Night | 655077 | 1516885 |
| 2005 | Midnight | 14129 | 76889 |
| 2005 | Morning | 717753 | 2801079 |
| 2005 | Afternoon | 1108381 | 2738639 |
| 2005 | Night | 697598 | 1523989 |

And this is my code:

```
# To plot the line graph
timeofday_plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(data= All_Flights_Combined_TimeOfDay, aes(x =TimeOfDay, y=Delay_Count, group=Year, color=Year)) + 
  geom_line(data=All_Flights_Combined_TimeOfDay, aes(x =TimeOfDay, y=Total_Count , group=Year, color=Year))+ 
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Midnight","Morning","Afternoon","Night"))+
  xlab("TimeOfDay")+
  ylab("Number of Flights")+
  ggtitle("Total number of Flights VS Flight Delays") +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("2003 Delay_Count" = "red", 
                                "2004 Delay_Count" = "green", 
                                "2005 Delay_Count" = "blue", 
                                "2003 Total_Count" = "orange", 
                                "2004 Total_Count" = "yellow", 
                                "2005 Total_Count" = "purple"),
                     breaks = c("2003 Delay_Count",
                                "2004 Delay_Count",
                                "2005 Delay_Count",
                                "2003 Total_Count", 
                                "2004 Total_Count", 
                                "2005 Total_Count"))

timeofday_plot
```

[This is the plot it is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIydT.jpg)

I have tried adding themes but to no avails.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your code and `scale_color_manual` work reshape your data to long then use e.g. `unite` to combine the tyep of count with year so that you can apply your custom color palette:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

All_Flights_Combined_TimeOfDay <- All_Flights_Combined_TimeOfDay %>% 
  pivot_longer(ends_with("Count"), names_to = "type", values_to = "Count") %>% 
  unite("type", Year, type, sep = " ", remove = FALSE)

ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = All_Flights_Combined_TimeOfDay, aes(x = TimeOfDay, y = Count, 
                                                       group = type, color = type)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Midnight", "Morning", "Afternoon", "Night")) +
  xlab("TimeOfDay") +
  ylab("Number of Flights") +
  ggtitle("Total number of Flights VS Flight Delays") +
  theme_classic() +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c(
      "2003 Delay_Count" = "red",
      "2004 Delay_Count" = "green",
      "2005 Delay_Count" = "blue",
      "2003 Total_Count" = "orange",
      "2004 Total_Count" = "yellow",
      "2005 Total_Count" = "purple"
    ),
    breaks = c(
      "2003 Delay_Count",
      "2004 Delay_Count",
      "2005 Delay_Count",
      "2003 Total_Count",
      "2004 Total_Count",
      "2005 Total_Count"
    )
  )
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
All_Flights_Combined_TimeOfDay <- data.frame(
  Year = c(
    2003L, 2003L, 2003L, 2003L,
    2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2004L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L
  ),
  TimeOfDay = c(
    "Midnight", "Morning",
    "Afternoon", "Night", "Midnight", "Morning", "Afternoon", "Night",
    "Midnight", "Morning", "Afternoon", "Night"
  ),
  Delay_Count = c(
    9934L, 544278L, 819926L,
    485066L, 13458L, 687543L, 1056605L, 655077L, 14129L, 717753L,
    1108381L, 697598L
  ),
  Total_Count = c(
    53321L, 2520172L, 2555560L,
    1359486L, 71595L, 2782548L, 2758242L, 1516885L, 76889L,
    2801079L, 2738639L, 1523989L
  )
)
```